# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to improve a game of battleships. The original version works fine with no errors. I have written code to help overcome the fact that the first version places the ships in the same place every time so I have started with one ship (made of two squares). I have done this by creating two functions: the first generates a random coordinate...

```
# Destroyer (2 squares)
def Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player):
    rand_col_1 = randint(0,11)
    if rand_col_1 <= 5:
        rand_row_1 = randint(0,11)
    else:
        rand_row_1 = randint(6,11)
    return rand_col_1
    return rand_row_1
    if Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] == 'X':
        Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)
    else:
        Deploy_Destroyer_2(Player)
```

and the second trials this co-ordinate against the conditions (if it will fit on the board and which rotation it can be placed).

```
def Deploy_Destroyer_2(Player):
    if rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 == 6:
        #can be 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(1,4) and rand_row_1 in range(1,10):
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(5,10) and rand_row_1 in range(7,10):
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 == 0:
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 == 0) or (rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 ==6):
        #can be one or four
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,2)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2 or 3
        rand_position_1 = randint(2,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2 or 4
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,2)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_row_1 == 0 and rand_col_1 in range(1,4)) or (rand_row_1 == 6 and rand_col_1 in range(6,10)):
        #can be 1, 3 or 4
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 in range(1,5)) or (rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 in range(7,10)):
        #can be 1, 2 or 4
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 in range(1,10):
        #can be 1, 2 or 3... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(1,10) and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2, 3 or 4
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
```

After applying my code I get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 310, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in PrintBoards
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

and here is the `PrintBoards` function

```
def PrintBoards(Player,Opponent):
    print ' '*10, 'PLAYER', ' '*30, 'OPPONENT'
    letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L']
    for x in range(6):
        print letters[x],"  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Player[x]))," "*18,"| ","  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Opponent[x]))
    for x in range(6,12):
        print letters[x],"  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Player[x]))," | ","  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Opponent[x]))
    print " ","  ".join(map(str,range(1,10)))," 10 11 12","  ","  ".join(map(str,range(1,10)))," 10 11 12"
```

and here is the `DisplayChar` function

```
def DisplayChar(x):
    if x==0: 
        return '?'
    elif x==1:
        return ' '
    elif x==2:
        return 'X'
    elif x==3:
        return ' '
    elif x==4:
        return '*'
```

I tried editing the above function to this...

```
def DisplayChar(x):
        if x==0: 
            return '?'
        elif x==2:
            return 'X'
        elif x==4:
            return '*'
        else:
            return ' '
```

However it gave me this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 309, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in PrintBoards
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

I also tried printing the lists Player and Opponent after the `PrintBoards` function to ensure that they contain 0s and 1s (referring to the `DisplayChar` function) which they do (when inserted into the original, not when I put my new and very long code in)

This next bit is in response to Michael

```
PLAYER                                OPPONENT
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
A                                                       |  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
<function Deploy_Destroyer_1 at 0x1c2634>
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 314, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in PrintBoards
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

After someone kindly pointed out I had assigned the function instead of called it, I've found that another error occurred (I don't think Python likes me)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 313, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in PrintBoards
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Below I've also included where I called the function in case I've done something silly

```
Player, Opponent = InitBoards()
Player = DeployFleet(Player), Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)
PrintBoards(Player,Opponent)
```

I changed it to what Micheal0x2a said and it ran with no errors however the ship that the code is placing disappeared

From what I understand, the `PrintBoards` function prints the board for the `Player` by mapping the items in the list to the `DisplayChar` function (if 2 is an item in the list, it prints X etc). So my novice knowledge tells me that the `Deploy_Destroyer_1` function should be called in `Player =` in the `Main` function (included above) to ensure that the item in the list is changed, therefore the character printed should change.

I’m guessing that there is something wrong with my new code (`Deploy_Destroyer_1`) which doesn’t do this correctly (either doesn’t change the item in the list therefore doesn’t print the correct character, or something else which I can’t think of).

However there is also a big chance that I have confused myself

I have only been learning Python for a couple of weeks so if anyone needs more detail in order to help me please ask

Comment: You need to show the full traceback, so we can see where the error is being raised.

Comment: does that help at all? you might need the whole program? argh

Comment: Your problem is definitely not the `TypeError`.

Comment: got any suggestions @septi?

Comment: The lines that it highlights are ones which worked in the original. Any chance it's the parameters of my new functions? Or could it be something else completely?

Comment: We don't know about the `PrintBoards` function, but I guess there's a `join` inside it that joins together all cell contents. This does not work with Nones.

Comment: So what do I need to do? Yes there is a `join` in the PrintBoards function, but what exactly is a None?

Comment: Edit the question to add the code for the `PrintBoards` function, since that's where the problem is, and we'll be better able to help.

Comment: Ok, the `DisplayChar` function needs to return the empty string `""` as default value, then it should work.

Comment: I've added the `DisplayChar` function: doesn't it already do as you've said above?

Answer (score 157):

If you've arrived here because you were looking for the root cause of "`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found`", it can come from doing something along these lines...

```
','.join([None])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know. 
This can also happen if your list has other stuff in it, but stil contains a None. 
[None, 'foo', 'bar']
Now I have to find the method to clear 'None's from the array

Comment: This is a nice way to do it: >>>  filter(None, ['a', None, 'c'])

Comment: @NoelEvans: +1, but you need to point out that this will not filter None from the list, but also any other falsey values.

Comment: As inspired by @NoelEvans I found this to be useful: ','.join(map(str,[None]))

Comment: You, sir, just saved me from spending countless hours looking desperately at Google Cloud logs, which are all but self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely somewhere within these 4 lines:

```
for x in range(6):
    print letters[x],"  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Player[x]))," "*18,"| ","  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Opponent[x]))
for x in range(6,12):
    print letters[x],"  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Player[x]))," | ","  ".join(map(DisplayChar,Opponent[x]))
```

Within these lines, you've used a `join` statement multiple times. The `join` statement requires a list of strings in order to work. However, when you're mapping `DisplayChar` to `Player[x]`, the `DisplayChar` function is returning the value `None` instead of a string of some sort.

If you look at the `DisplayChar` function, it handles values only from 0 to 4. The lists you use probably include additional numbers or characters. If `x` happened to be something like `5`, `DisplayChar` will terminate and simply return the value `None`. Remember, functions return the value `None` by default.

You either need to handle these additional numbers within `DisplayChar`, or modify `DisplayChar` to contain an `else` statement to return an empty string, like so:

```
def DisplayChar(x):
    if x==0: 
        return '?'
    elif x==1:
        return ' '
    elif x==2:
        return 'X'
    elif x==3:
        return ' '
    elif x==4:
        return '*'
    else:
        return ' '
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I think I might know what's going on, given the new edits.

Notice when you were printing out `Player[x]`, it printed `<function Deploy_Destroyer_1 at 0x1c2634>` the second time around?

That means somewhere, buried deep inside your code, you've done something to the effect of `Player[row] = Deploy_Destroyer_1` (notice the missing parenthesis!). Instead of calling the function, you've *assigned* the function.

Hunting for, and adding the missing parenthesis should most likely solve the problem.

**Edit 2:**

I think your problem is with this line: `Player = DeployFleet(Player), Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)`

If you try doing a `print Player` immediately after, I think you'll most likely see a large list of numbers, followed by `None`.

This is because the `DeployFleet` function is returning the table (I think?) whereas the `Deploy_Destroyer_1` function returns nothing. Instead, it just mutates the `Player` table.

To fix this, try doing either this:

```
Player = DeployFleet(Player)
Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)
```

...or modify `Deployer_Destroyer_1` so that it returns `Player` when it's finished, so you can do this:

```
Player = DeployFleet(Player)
Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)
```

Comment: Player is a define list in a different function
`def InitBoards():
    #The following convention is used for storing the state of a square:
    #0=Unknown
    #1= Empty
    #2= Occupied
    #3= Missed
    #4= Hit (player or opponent)
    # Initially, the player's board is all empty, the opponent's is all unknown
    Player = [[1]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]
    Opponent = [[0]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]
    return Player,Opponent`
Here's what I thought: map() checks state of square/cell and prints the correct string using `DisplayChar` function. I tried changing Display

Comment: @BLeeM - just right after the `for` loops, could you try writing `print Player[x], Opponent[x]` so that we can check what's actually contained within those lists? Right now, we're just making guesses as to what's inside those values, and I'd like to know for certain.

Comment: It's defined in the `InitBoards` function (where the 1 and 0 refer to `DisplayChar`)
`def InitBoards():
    
    # Initially, the player's board is all empty, the opponent's is all unknown
    Player = [[1]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]
    Opponent = [[0]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]

    return Player,Opponent`
So it just prints all the 1s and 0s because we don't know anything about the opponents and I haven't deployed my fleet yet

Comment: @BleeM -- Regardless, could you still print them out? Something could be modifying them in unexpected ways. Besides, when debugging, it's always good to be paranoid and test your assumptions -- if your assumptions were correct, there wouldn't be a bug :)

Comment: It doesn't reach the `print` it stops just as before and gives me the `traceback` error :( and thanks for the advice!

Comment: @BleeM - Sorry, I think I'm getting mixed up. Which traceback are we referring to? Could you edit your question, and underneath everything, post everything you tried and the complete stacktrace that appeared after you modified the `DisplayChar` function?

Comment: @BLeeM -- are you sure the print statement doesn't work? Could you try changing `PrintBoards` to look like [this](http://pastebin.com/5UhBDd5x)? Use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) to copy everything that the program prints out, including the complete error message.

Comment: thanks for your edited part.. you were right! however I still get an error after adjusting :( I've edited my question with where I call the function and the error message to see if you had any other ideas. Thank you

Comment: @BLeeM -- at this point, StackOverflow has been not-so-subtly hinting that I should probably start wrapping things up here. What I recommend you do now is spend some time debugging what you have: add a crapton of print statements everywhere so that you can test what every variable actually looks like vs what you think is happening, try using a debugger, etc. Try and avoid making any assumptions, and try and spend a good chunk of time just picking through your code. If you run into something you don't understand during this process, post a new question about it (getting fresh eyes will help).

Comment: I'll keep an eye on your profile for a couple of days, and will do my best to pop in and answer any new questions you have (assuming nobody beat me to it!).

Answer (score 1):

Your DisplayChar function does not have a default value. This would do no harm if you'd be handling all possible cases for `x`, but apparently you're not. Try

```
def DisplayChar(x):
    if x == 0: 
        return '?'
    elif x == 2:
        return 'X'
    elif x == 4:
        return '*'
    else:
        return ' '
```

but this will probably yield blank strings where you don't expect them.

Generally, I'd recommend going through a good Python tutorial first. All of your above code can be greatly simplified.

Comment: changed it to that... it did print another line of the boards but got this error instead :S `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 308, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in PrintBoards
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration`

Comment: Right. You probably meant `DisplayChar(Player[x])` instead of `map(DisplayChar,Player[x])`

Answer (score 1):

use this if any this type error came:
for example
','.join((map(str,video_url))
map function help your to change tuble to str