# Delete all vowels from a string using a list-comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve a challenge on Codewars.

> Trolls are attacking your comment section!
>
> A common way to deal with this situation is to remove all of the
>   vowels from the trolls' comments, neutralizing the threat.
>
> Your task is to write a function that takes a string and return a new
>   string with all vowels removed.
>
> For example, the string "This website is for losers LOL!" would become
>   "Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!".
>
> Note: for this kata y isn't considered a vowel.

This is working:

```py
def disemvowel(string):
    output = []
    for char in string:
        if char not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            output.extend(char)
    return "".join(output)
```

But I want to do it in one line with a list comprehension. I tried this:

```py
return "".join([[].extend(char) for char in string if char not in "aeiouAEIOU"])
```

... but I'm getting

```py
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581824/correct-code-to-remove-the-vowels-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Also related, seems to be a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852324/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-nonetype-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to make a list within your list-comprehension; you can just use the existing list:

```
return "".join([char for char in x if char not in "aeiouAEIOU"])
```

Note that we could even omit the list comprehension and just use a generator expression (by omitting the square brackets), but `join()` works internally by converting the sequence to a list anyway, so in this case using a list-comprehension is actually quicker.

Comment: @hallowed: that's just the inner part of the `[..]`: `''.join(char for char in x if char.lower() not in "aeoui")`

Comment: in python 3 you can do: `x.translate(str.maketrans("", "", 'aeiouAEIOU'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    vowels = 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'
    for a in vowels:
      string_ = string_.replace(a, '')
    return string_
```

Comment: "But I want to do it in one line with a list comprehension."